# Connecting to Ubuntu 16.04 LDAPv3 server from macOS clients

Tags: mac, network, ldap, directory-utility

I've been working on an Ubuntu 16.04 server that has LDAPv3 active via OpenLDAP, my client machines are all macOS from `El Capitan` upto `High Sierra`.

On the server I have the `samba` schema implemented, along with the `apple` schema implemented:

```
serveradmin@Magic:~$ sudo ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=schema,cn=config dn
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={0}core,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={1}cosine,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={2}nis,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={4}ppolicy,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={5}samba,cn=schema,cn=config
dn: cn={6}apple,cn=schema,cn=config
serveradmin@Magic:~$
```

On my client machine I am able to connect to the LDAPv3 server from the Directory Utility by changing the connection type to `RFC2307` and editing the base to be `ou=People,dc=salty,dc=domain,dc=com`. I can see my users in the Directory Editor:

[image]

I can connect to my file share over `smb://<IP>`. However, when I try to log in as one of my users it will not allow me to log in. The log files show something like the following:

```
<DATE> <TIME> CDT - AID 0x000..26 93.7657.7246, Node: /LDAPv3/10.0.1.57, Module ldap __odnode_copy_record_block_invoke: 4101: No predicates provided
```

or

```
<DATE> <TIME> CDT - AID 0x000..1042 394.3858, Node: /LDAPv3/10.0.1.57, Module: ldap - failed to retrieve password for credential
```

No matter what I do it seems like I keep getting the same error message. What is causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this helps...

in order to get it to work with Mac OSX client you need to add these 2 lines in your smb.conf file (/etc/samba/smb.conf):
ea support = yes
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr

src: [enter link description here](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/mac-osx-client-and-linux-samba-share.77380/)

Comment: My Samba share works, it's the ldap server that doesn't work